# How to trigger JavaScript event when input field is cleared?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an **instant search box**. When user start typing in the search box, it triggers a javascript event to hide the blog posts (`#home`) and search results will be shown instead (this part of the script is not included below). However, after user **cleared** the search box, they see just a blank page as the `display` of `#home` is still set to be `none`.

How can I make JavaScript detect the user **cleared the input filed** at `#search-input` and make `#home` display `true` again?

```
document.getElementById('search-input').oninput = function() {
    document.getElementById('home').style.display = 'none';
};
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through the `input` event listener. To hide the `#home` element, add a conditional to check if the input has a value. If it doesn't then you hide it. To bring it back you do the opposite but **only** if `#home` is hidden:

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');
const home = document.getElementById('home');

searchInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (!this.value) {
        home.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (this.value && home.style.display === 'none') {
      home.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="search-input" type="text"/>

<div id="home">
  Sample Content
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help of Carl Edwards!

Here is the final code that works perfectly:

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');
const home = document.getElementById('home');
const results = document.getElementById('results');

searchInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (this.value) {
        home.style.display = 'none';
        results.style.display = 'inline';
    } else if (!this.value && home.style.display === 'none') {
      home.style.display = 'block';
      results.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```